# convert 1 row as column and concatenate the results to the corresponding column

Tags: mysql, concat, group-concatenation

I have 2 tables

**table 1 - apps**

```
-----------
id  | name
-----------
1   | abc
-----------
2   | sdf
-----------
3   | dfg
-----------
```

**table 2 - contacts**

```
------------------------
id  | cnt_type  | cnt_id
------------------------
1   | manager   |    20
------------------------
1   | supervisor |  32
------------------------
1   | teamlead   | 45
------------------------
1   | teamlead  | 54
------------------------
2   | manager    |   20
------------------------
2   | supervisor |  32
------------------------
```

I need a view as below where cnt_type rows are represented as columns and the corresponding values are concatenated and group by the cnt_type per id...

```
---------------------------------------
id  | manager | supervisor  | teamlead
--------------------------------------
1   | 20      |    32       | 45, 54
--------------------------------------
2   | 20      |    32       |
--------------------------------------
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How many `cnt_type` should be on table contacts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## PROPOSED QUERY

```
SELECT
    A.id,
    IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT B.cnt_id),'') 'manager',
    IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT C.cnt_id),'') 'supervisor',
    IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT D.cnt_id),'') 'teamlead'
FROM apps A
LEFT JOIN contacts B ON A.id = B.id AND B.cnt_type='manager'
LEFT JOIN contacts C ON A.id = C.id AND C.cnt_type='supervisor'
LEFT JOIN contacts D ON A.id = D.id AND D.cnt_type='teamlead'
WHERE ISNULL(B.cnt_id)+ISNULL(C.cnt_id)+ISNULL(D.cnt_id) < 3
GROUP BY A.id;
```

## SAMPLE DATA

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS kumar;
CREATE DATABASE kumar;
USE kumar
CREATE TABLE apps
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE TABLE contacts
(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    cnt_type VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    cnt_id INT NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO apps (name) VALUES ('abc'),('sdf'),('dfg');
INSERT INTO contacts (id,cnt_type,cnt_id) VALUES
(1,'manager',20), (1,'supervisor',32), (1,'teamlead',45),
(1,'teamlead',54), (2,'manager',20), (2,'supervisor',32);
```

## SAMPLE DATA LOADED

```
mysql> DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS kumar;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE kumar;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> USE kumar
Database changed
mysql> CREATE TABLE apps
    -> (
    ->     id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->     name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    ->     PRIMARY KEY (id)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE contacts
    -> (
    ->     id INT NOT NULL,
    ->     cnt_type VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    ->     cnt_id INT NOT NULL
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO apps (name) VALUES ('abc'),('sdf'),('dfg');
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> INSERT INTO contacts (id,cnt_type,cnt_id) VALUES
    -> (1,'manager',20), (1,'supervisor',32), (1,'teamlead',45),
    -> (1,'teamlead',54), (2,'manager',20), (2,'supervisor',32);
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql>
```

## SAMPLE DATA IN TABLES

```
mysql> select * from apps;
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | abc  |
|  2 | sdf  |
|  3 | dfg  |
+----+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from contacts;
+----+------------+--------+
| id | cnt_type   | cnt_id |
+----+------------+--------+
|  1 | manager    |     20 |
|  1 | supervisor |     32 |
|  1 | teamlead   |     45 |
|  1 | teamlead   |     54 |
|  2 | manager    |     20 |
|  2 | supervisor |     32 |
+----+------------+--------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## PROPOSED QUERY EXECUTED

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->     A.id,
    ->     IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT B.cnt_id),'') 'manager',
    ->     IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT C.cnt_id),'') 'supervisor',
    ->     IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT D.cnt_id),'') 'teamlead'
    -> FROM apps A
    -> LEFT JOIN contacts B ON A.id = B.id AND B.cnt_type='manager'
    -> LEFT JOIN contacts C ON A.id = C.id AND C.cnt_type='supervisor'
    -> LEFT JOIN contacts D ON A.id = D.id AND D.cnt_type='teamlead'
    -> WHERE ISNULL(B.cnt_id)+ISNULL(C.cnt_id)+ISNULL(D.cnt_id) < 3
    -> GROUP BY A.id;
+----+---------+------------+----------+
| id | manager | supervisor | teamlead |
+----+---------+------------+----------+
|  1 | 20      | 32         | 45,54    |
|  2 | 20      | 32         |          |
+----+---------+------------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks Rolando for the quick reply, I had been scratching my head last couple of hours.

Comment: What do i need to do to include all rows from apps table. With the query above, i am able to retrieve all the rows from contacts table that have a matching row in apps table.

Comment: If you want all apps to appear, even if there are no contacts, simply remove `WHERE ISNULL(B.cnt_id)+ISNULL(C.cnt_id)+ISNULL(D.cnt_id) < 3`.

Comment: Awesome, you are the BEST. I found a new friend on this site.